# CSS mobile website - why so high values?

Tags: css, mobile

To fit my WP website for mobiles I use

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 780px) {}
```

However, to fit everything properly I have to use giant values, like `font-size: 4em;`, `header {height: 200px;}` (when it's 100 on the desktop version). Is it normal?

The main problem is with Gallery plugin - by default thumbs have size e.g. 200x300, and on the mobile version they are really tiny!

Or maybe there is a better way to make a website mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say you are not setting your viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

---

Nowadays, most mobile phones have a very high dpi; for instance, the iphone 6 plus has a full 1080p display, so when you make something 100px tall, it is only 1/19 of the screen height.

By setting the viewport to the device-width, you are telling the browser to render the page using a more standard dpi (for instance, the iphone 6 would be something like 424x600ish). That way, all of your content automatically scales.

Comment: I have it set so the problem must be somewhere else.
Maybe it will be easier with a live example: [www.kama.besaba.com]
(right now for mobiles I have only `.wrap {width:95%;} `)

Comment: @Dandy I need more information then. Do you have a link to the page?

Comment: @Dandy I see it. You have unicode quotation marks in your viewport meta tag. When you pull up the source code, it looks like this: `<meta name="”viewport”" content="width=device-width," initial-scale="1\`"/>` You also have a bad character in that initial-scale, the `. What IDE are you using? If you are not using an IDE, I would strongly recommend it, as it will catch things like this (and not let them happen in the first place, since it encodes the file as UTF-8)

Comment: @Dandy If you are a Mac user, I recommend [Coda](http://panic.com/coda). If you are a Windows, user, maybe Dreamweaver.

Comment: Now it works! I've only copied the version of the meta you gave me. How is it possible that after pulling up the source code it has such "extra" characters and in my *.php file there are no such characters?

Comment: Because your browser is seeing the unicode quotation marks and assuming that you want them there as different characters, and will automatically surround them with UTF-8 quotes. This is because unicode characters are not special characters in HTML; they are treated the same way that ordinary letters are. If you try adding something like `<div class=test>`, you'll notice your browser does the same thing. You may put no quotation marks, but your browser will turn it into `<div class="test">`.